# Jumping to a line number in lldb

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos, lldb

How do you jump to a specific source line in lldb?  In gdb it would be "jump X" where X is the line number but the only reference I can find for lldb is http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html which says:

> Skip 8 bytes ahead of the current program counter (instruction
>   pointer). Note that we use backticks to evaluate an expression and
>   insert the scalar result in LLDB.
>
> ```
> (gdb) jump *$pc+8
> (lldb) register write pc `$pc+8`
> ```

FWIW, on MacOS, replacing "pc" with "rip" seems to work.

But jumping to specific lines seems quite difficult using this method.  Is there a better way to jump in lldb?

Comment: PC (program counter) and IP (instruction pointer) are both (conceptually) the same thing, they're just different names used in different architectures.  PC is used in PowerPC- and ARM-based systems (the latter of which includes all current iOS devices).  IP is used on x86, except IP is the original term from the 16-bit days—the 32-bit version is called EIP, and the 64-bit version is called RIP.  So for iOS targets, you use `$pc`, but for Mac OS X, you use `$eip` (32-bit programs) or `$rip` (64-bit programs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of how to do this in Python was added to the lldb repository a couple of days ago.  See http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/python/jump.py

Save the contents of that file to your home directory, maybe something like `~/lldb/jump.py` and load it into your lldb with a command like

```
command script import ~/lldb/jump.py
```

(or put this in your `~/.lldbinit` file) and you'll have a `jump` command.

Note that with ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) in Objective-C programs, you can screw up your program SUPER easy by jumping around - a lot of jumps that look harmless are actually not.  This is definitely in the "user beware" / "good luck with that" category of debugger tricks.

Comment: Thanks, that's a start.  Seems to mostly work, but already I've run into some problems.  Is there a discussion forum for it?  Its baffling to me that gdb seems so much better than lldb in this regard.  I just figured I was missing something basic.

Comment: You could try sending mail to the lldb-dev mailing list, see http://lldb.llvm.org/ for details.  Sean wrote the python script the other day as an example implementation - I imagine it will be a "patches are happily accepted" type of conversation but feel free to detail what problems you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

As an update, I leave here a new feature from the LLDB tutorial: http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html

> Finally, lldb has a run until line or frame exit stepping mode:
> (lldb) thread until 100
>
> This command will run the thread in the current frame till it reaches line 100 in this frame or stops if it leaves the current frame. This is a pretty close equivalent to gdb's "until" command.

Thus, `(lldb) thread until <lineno>` does the trick for the current thread.

Also, `(lldb) help thread until` contains additional options.